# Select parts of a table with a for loop and save to file

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables `A` and `codes`, which are created as part of a WITH query:

```
WITH 

A as
(
 select id, value1, value2, code 
 from table_X where...
), 
codes as
(
 select distinct code from table_X where...
)
...
```

So, table `A` is like:

```
+------+--------+--------+--------+
| id   | value1 | value2 |  code  |
+------+--------+--------+--------+
| id1  |   10   |   11   |   001  |
+------+--------+-------+--------+
| id1  |   20   |   33   |   002  |
+------+--------+--------+--------+
| id2  |   5    |   23   |   001  |
+------+--------+--------+--------+
| id2  |   8    |   13   |   002  |
+------+--------+--------+--------+
| id3  |   6    |   15   |   003  |
+------+--------+--------+--------+
```

and `codes` like:

```
+--------+
|  code  |
+--------+
|   001  |
+--------+
|   002  |
+--------+
|   003  |
+--------+
```

I would now like to select all rows from `A` for each code in `codes` and save those table as csv/json files as described in the following pseudo-sql code:

```
WITH 

A as
(
 select id, value1, value2, code 
 from table_X where...
), 
codes as
(
 select distinct code from table_X where...
)
FOR code in codes:
   Select id, value1, value2 from A
   where code = code
   save_to_json('code/data.json')
```

where, possibly, each table is saved in a folder named after the unique code used in the for loop.

Comment: It is Microsoft SQL server. Thanks for pointing that.

Comment: Even if it might be possible via SQL, I strongly recommend to use SSIS for this type of task... the filesystem tasks (and I guess even the JSon parsing) is way easier to maintain..